# Can I make key-binding add-on for a browser game?

Tags: python

I was adviced to post here from Programmers SE.

So we got this Drakensang Online, a RPG browser game. I got 7 skill slots on the skill bar but the last skill slot is kinda far and uncomfortable for me to press. Many games have key-binding options.

My question is, can I make a add-on for key binding, as the original game doesn't allow it. A program that will listen for key presses while I'm playing in the browser, then will point to the original key slot that the game client is listening for.

Is this posible? - If so can I use Python 3?
Is it legal?

PS: I am not a developer of Drakensang Online, nor a moderator, I just wanna make my gaming expirience better, specially in PvP.

Comment: It may be overkill, but in Windows you can modify your registry to remap one key to another. I use [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) to do it for me.

Comment: It's legal alright.....

Comment: There's also [AutoHotkey](http://superuser.com/tags/autohotkey/info), that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Python is probably not the right tool for the job. You should look at the driver software for your keyboard first. I believe to remember that for example the Logitech driver software does allow you to rebind keys (so that when you press <kbd>1</kbd> a key event for <kbd>2</kbd> is generated instead). Second I would look into scripting tools specifically designed for these kind of tasks (e.g [AuotIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) or any other macor recording utility, Google is your friend in this case).

You should also check out [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/)